# writing a for loop to generate tab delimited files in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have several files that are in the format of "XXX.qassoc" saved in a folder. I am trying to write a for loop that converts these files to txt like this all at once.

```
A <- read.table(file = "XXX.qassoc", quote = "\"", comment.char = "",header=TRUE)
write.table(A, file = "XXX.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know what I can do? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set directory with `setwd('path')` and then:

```
library(rebus)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

list.files() %>%
    str_subset("\\.qassoc$") %>% 
    walk(~ {A <- read.table(file = .x, quote = "\"", comment.char = "",header=TRUE)
           write.table(A, file = str_replace(.x, '\\.qassoc$', '.txt'), sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)})
```